The Lennard-Jones potential for stationary particles
Suppose I have $N=5$ Argon particles: $A(1,4)$, $B(2,2)$, $C(3,1)$, $D(4,3)$, and $E(0,0)$.
Three particles $\{A, C, D\}$ are mobile. Two particles $\{B, E\}$ are immobile or stationary or fixed.
Suppose $MovingSet=\{A, C, D\}$, and $FixedSet=\{B, E\}$.
$\begin{array}
{r | c | c | c | c | c}  & 
A & C & D & B & E \\ \hline 
A & \times & E_{AC} & E_{AD} & E_{AB} & E_{AE} \\ \hline 
C & - & \times & E_{CD} & E_{CB} & E_{CE} \\ \hline 
D & - & - & \times & E_{DB} & E_{DE} \\ \hline 
B & - & - & - & \times & E_{BE} \\ \hline 
E & - & - & - & - & \times \\ \hline 
\end{array}$
What will be the effect of immobile particles on the mobile particles when it comes to computing LJ potentials?
Say, the LJ potential between moving particles is $$E_{(moving, moving)} =E_{AC} + E_{AD} + E_{CD} \tag{3.1}$$
Say, the LJ potential between moving and fixed particles is  $$E_{(moving, fixed)} =E_{AB} + E_{AE} + E_{CB}+ E_{CE}+ E_{DB}+ E_{DE} \tag{4.1}$$
What will be the effect of $(4.1)$ on $(3.1)$?
Apparently, we have to subtract or add something to $(3.1)$.
What will the calculation be like?

Personally, I'd approach this system by treating the fixed particles as having infinite mass. That way, you don't have to think of (3.1) and (4.1) as separate at all. You can just add the potential of each particle pair. Just be aware, that this will offset your answer by the fixed-fixed potential (which will be constant, so won't affect any physical conclusions of the system).
tl;dr: there's nothing special about the fixed particles, as opposed to moving ones, in terms of determining the energy of the system, as long as you're clear about what question you're trying to answer!

as long as you're clear about what question you're trying to answer! --- I am 100% clear. I will post a follow-up question very soon.
